# How to make a div rotate automatically every second?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to make the div (box shape) to rotate clockwise and change color every second automatically. My friend did the change color and clock display, and it works. I tried to copy the format and use it for rotation, and it doesn't rotate automatically every second. And I really don't know how to do it.

```
function everySecond(){
    var newDate = new Date();
    var s = newDate.getSeconds();
    var m = newDate.getMinutes();
    var h = newDate.getHours();

    s = modifyTime(s);
    m = modifyTime(m);

    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
$("#ball").css('background-color', randomColor());

}

function randomColor(){
    var choice = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for(var i=0; i<6; i++){
        color += choice[Math.floor(Math.random()*16)];
    }
    return color;
}

$("#ball").css({'transform' : 'rotate('+ 30 +'deg)'});

function modifyTime(t){
    if(t<10){
        t="0"+t;
    };
    return t;
}

setInterval(everySecond, 1000);
```

Comment: `'rotate('+ 30 +'deg)'` ===  `'rotate(30deg)'`... is a fixed rotation of 30deg

Comment: I tried 'rotate(' + s + 'deg)', it doesn't work at all

Comment: The line is outside the everySecond function. So, it is only executed once, not every second. And only inside the everySecond function does s have a meaningful value.

Comment: My friend's random color things are also outside the every Second function entirely, yet the color still changes every second automatically.

Comment: The randomColor function is called from within the everySecond function...

Comment: `I tried` - well, what is `s` ... you'd need to add the rotating inside the everySecond function'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#ball").css({'transform' : 'rotate('+ 30 +'deg)'});
```

As others have pointed out, above line only rotates to 30 degrees. We need to modify this line and put it inside the `everySecond()` function.

```
var degreesToRoatate = 30;
$("#ball").css({'transform' : 'rotate('+ degreesToRoatate +'deg)'});
```

Now,  we need to map the value of `s` (which is seconds) to `degreesToRotate`.

range of s -> 0 to 59

range of degreesToRotate -> 0 to 359.

```
degreesToRotate = s*6;
```

The div will be rotated by 180 degrees at 30 seconds.

Final code becomes:

```
    function everySecond(){
    var newDate = new Date();
    var s = newDate.getSeconds();
    var m = newDate.getMinutes();
    var h = newDate.getHours();
    var degreesToRotate = s*6;

    s = modifyTime(s);
    m = modifyTime(m);

    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;

    $("#ball").css({'transform' : 'rotate('+ degreesToRotate +'deg)'});
    $("#ball").css('background-color', randomColor());

}

function randomColor(){
    var choice = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for(var i=0; i<6; i++){
        color += choice[Math.floor(Math.random()*16)];
    }
    return color;
}

function modifyTime(t){
    if(t<10){
        t="0"+t;
    };
    return t;
}

setInterval(everySecond, 1000);
```

Edit: Just tested this. Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jj5hrew1/

Comment: Yeah!!! It works.......Could you also help me with some css and html??? I know it's kinda off topic........But you looks really good with coding....My friend is on Vacation, won't be back in US until next month.....Damn it!!! :((

Comment: Is there anyway I can upload the entire css and html in here??? let me just edit question....

Comment: @user3390471 Yeah. I'd love to help. Edit: You sure my answer works correctly? Because I just noticed formula for degreesToRotate should be (s+1)*6-1

Comment: Oh! Who cares if the formular is correct ! lol....This isn't for math class.....This is for a design class......We're supposed to make an abstract clock as a team.......So my friend and I teamed up, he's in computer science major, I'm in design major....I mark up the design, he codes...perfect! Then he goes for vacation, cuz he asked to take all the finals ahead, and he passed them all !!! What a genius..........So jealous~~~~...... And he left me here alone to suffer the projects.....>->

Comment: So I guess I can just edit on fiddle, and send you the link, so you can see the whole thing....It's almost done, just one more thing, I want the circle color changes after the ball rotate 360.....again, no need to be precise in math.....so basically, the ball act like second, and the circle act like minute

Comment: Basically I don't need the circle to change color every second, I need it to change color every minute....wait....every minute sound like too long....maybe every 15 second, or every 30 second......Thank you, Thank you^^

Comment: lol.......Sorry~~~~~That's what happened when a designer forced to code......very clumsy.......

Comment: @user3390471 Just put the color changing line in an _if condition_. like if you want it to change every 15 seconds : `if(s%15==0){$("#ball").css('background-color', randomColor());}`

Comment: It actually broke the whole thing......I have two shapes there, one is circle, one is ball, when I put the circle in if statement, the ball dispeared....

Comment: Oh....sorry, it works.....I tried to change the  id name, and forgot to change the CSS.....That broke the whole thing......lol

Answer (score 1):

I've tested this rotate function on all browsers, hope this is what you were looking for.

**Rotation**

```
function rotateDiv(divObject, degrees, animation) {
    /**
     * Rotates a div
     * Usage: Pass through one div object or an array of div objects, specify degrees and if you want an animation
     **/
    var totalDivs = Array.isArray(divObject) ? divObject.length : 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < totalDivs; i++) {
        var thisDiv = Array.isArray(divObject) ? divObject[i] : divObject;
        thisDiv.css({
            // Animation
            '-webkit-transition': '-webkit-transform '+(animation ? 1 : 0)+'s',
            '-moz-transition': '-moz-transform '+(animation ? 1 : 0)+'s',
            '-ms-transition': '-ms-transform '+(animation ? 1 : 0)+'s',
            '-o-transition': '-o-transform '+(animation ? 1 : 0)+'s',
            'transition': 'transform '+(animation ? 1 : 0)+'s',

            // Rotation
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+degrees+'deg)',
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate('+degrees+'deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotate('+degrees+'deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotate('+degrees+'deg)',
            'transform': 'rotate('+degrees+'deg)',
        })
    }
}
```

Usage

```
// Rotates 90 degrees clockwise with animation    
rotateDiv($('#div-to-rotate'), 90, true);

// Rotates 270 degrees clockwise without animation
rotateDiv($('.divs-to-rotate'), 270);

// Rotates multiple divs
rotateDiv([$('#div-1-to-rotate'), $('#div-2-to-rotate'), $('.more-divs')], 90, true);
```

**Final result**

```
var scale = 1;
setInterval(function() {
    $('#div-to-rotate').css({'background':randomColor()});
    rotateDiv($('#div-to-rotate'), 90*scale, true);
    scale > 3 ? scale = 0 : scale++
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the line doing the transform into the everySecond() function.
You also need to keep a variable that stores the current rotation and use it to make the div turn. 
Have also made the calls to the jQuery css() more similar.

```js
var curRotation = 0;

function everySecond()
{
    var newDate = new Date();
    var s = newDate.getSeconds();
    var m = newDate.getMinutes();
    var h = newDate.getHours();

    s = modifyTime(s);
    m = modifyTime(m);

    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;

    $("#ball").css('background-color', randomColor());
    
    $("#ball").css('transform', 'rotate('+ curRotation +'deg)');
    
    curRotation += 10;
    if (curRotation >= 360)
      curRotation = 0;
}

function randomColor(){
    var choice = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for(var i=0; i<6; i++){
        color += choice[Math.floor(Math.random()*16)];
    }
    return color;
}


function modifyTime(t){
    if(t<10){
        t="0"+t;
    };
    return t;
}

setInterval(everySecond, 1000);
```